# Adding/Deleting Dynamic Rows Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

I am trying to create a table that allows me to dynamically add and delete rows using javascript. I've looked at other solutions but can't quite get mine to function the same. I am able to add rows but can't delete.

Here is my HTML

```
<div id="entireRuleSet">
    <table border="1" id="newRuleTable">
        <tr>
            <td>Rule ID</td>
            <td>Data Column Name</td>
            <td>Operator</td>
            <td>Value</td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="idBox"/>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="columnBox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="operatorBox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" id="valueBox" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="button" id="deleteRow" value="Delete " />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <input type="button" id="addNewRule" value="Add new rule" onclick="insRow()" />
    <input type="button" id="saveButton" value="Save" />
</div>
<br />
<input type="button" id="addNewRuleSet" value="Add new rule set" />
```

Here is the javascript that I am using

```
function deleteRow(row) {
    var i = row.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex;
    document.getElementById('newRuleTable').deleteRow(i);
}

function insRow() {
    console.log('hi');
    var x = document.getElementById('newRuleTable');
    var new_row = x.rows[1].cloneNode(true);
    var len = x.rows.length;
    new_row.cells[0].innerHTML = len;

    var inp1 = new_row.cells[1].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp1.id += len;
    inp1.value = '';
    var inp2 = new_row.cells[2].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp2.id += len;
    inp2.value = '';
    var inp3 = new_row.cells[3].getElementsByTagName('input')[0];
    inp3.id += len;
    inp3.value = 'Delete';
    x.appendChild(new_row);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed to bind **`deleteRow(row)`** functionality to **`delete` button**

```
 <input type="button" id="deleteRow" value="Delete " />
```

change to

```
 <input type="button" id="deleteRow" value="Delete " onclick="deleteRow(this)"/>
```

`onclick="deleteRow(this)"`, pass `this` as parameter is mandatory as per your `deleteRow(row)` methid.

### [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2TtP/)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<td>
<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow(this)" id="deleteRow" value="Delete " />
</td>
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/q8CYC/4/)